# v.92 over HD Voice (via VoLTE)

Tags: android, modem

Is it possible to implement v.92 (or better) dialup networking on mobile phones that support HD voice via VoLTE?

Since I have unlimited voice I think this could be a great alternative to using our phone plans limited amount of mobile data.

Comment: "Implement *from* an application?" - likely not, discounting any other factor. Also, it seems like it'd be 'abysmal' throughput, VoLTE is what, 30-40k-bits-ps max?

Comment: No strict requirements that it be implemented from an application. My assumption was that having a wider frequency range would allow for similar or faster speeds.

Comment: I'm confused. I said wider frequency not higher frequencies and you're saying what matters is the size of the frequency range. If VoLTE and HD voice offer a wider frequency range why wouldn't we be able to increase modulation rates?

Comment: Either the first comment was changed or I was really tired >_<